# Hide class with a space in its name

Tags: javascript, css, greasemonkey

I have this simple GreaseMonkey script for hiding stuff in GMail:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        GMail
// @namespace   Namespace
// @include     https://mail.google.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

function addGlobalStyle(css) {
    var head, style;
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    if (!head) { return; }
    style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.innerHTML = css;
    head.appendChild(style);
}

addGlobalStyle(".mq, .oM, .AT, .Zs { display: none; }");
```

It works fine, but I have found that I need to hide an element on GMail which appears as:

```
<div class="P4mo8e gsl0xd hh">
```

I'm not sure how to hide those because I have tried:

```
addGlobalStyle(".mq, .oM, .AT, .Zs, .P4mo8e, .gsl0xd, .hh { display: none; }");
```

But that didn't work, as the content in that div still appears.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Remove the spaces if it needs to match when all classes are present.  E.g. `.P4mo8e.gsl0xd.hh`

Answer (score 4):

Those are multiple classes, not one class with spaces. This means that your style definition is not [specific](http://htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/specificity/) enough to override the styles set by Gmail. Try something like:

```
addGlobalStyle(".P4mo8e.gsl0xd.hh { display: none !important; }")
```

Although, that's still not guaranteed to work if the element has an inline style with an `!important` flag.

Comment: I've used `!important` in GMail user scripts and it does generally work. GMail's a bitch to hack cleanly, but I don't think it sets styles on any elements directly.

Answer (score 1):

Classes do *not* have spaces in the name. It's a way of applying more than one class to a HTML element. So `P4mo8e gsl0xd hh`is three classes, that presumably apply different styles, but they may exist to allow JavaScript to reference them.